# Difference in nuance between "antiparasitaire" and "lutte antiparasitaire"

Tags: sens, nuance

According to Google Translate:

- Lutte antiparasitaire = Pest control
- Antiparasitaire = Pest control
- Experts en lutte antiparasitaire = Pest control experts
- Experts en antiparasitaire = Pest control experts

**Is there a change in nuance due to the word "lutte"?**

The word "antiparasitaire" resembles "anti-pest" while I guess "lutte antiparasitaire" is simlar to "combatting anti-tests".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Antiparasitaire* can be an adjective or a noun, like "pest control" in English.

*Un antiparasitaire* (noun) is a product that will fight parasites and pests ("pest control product").

*Lutte antiparasitaire* (here the word is used as an adjective) is the fight against pests.

*Lutte antiparasitaire* can be used but I think in France *lutte contre les nuisibles* is more common (I guess there are regional variations, *lutte antiparasitaire* seems to be the [usual term](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agence_de_r%C3%A9glementation_de_la_lutte_antiparasitaire) in Canada). In France if I walk into a shop to buy a pest control product I look for the  *Traitement contre les nuisibles* sign.

*Un expert en antiparasitaires*<sup>1</sup> is a person who is an expert in products that fight parasites and pests.

*Un expert en lutte antiparasitaire* is a person who is an expert in pest control (a pest control/management expert), I expect they know a lot more than just how to use the products, they probably do the actual job.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Plural, there are several products.</sup>

Comment: Well, I guess Google does its best.  Thank you so much for the thorough explanation.  I am in Canada, so I should use the local term "antiparasitaire".